# Why Internet Explorer can not pull deployed web site correctly from server, but Chrome can?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, deployment

We are making asp.net web application and using twitter bootstrap. If we run the web site from localhost everything works well. But after deploying, there are lots of mis-rendered components, for example table cells are wrapping, transparent "loading" divs are not coming to the screen  etc. But there is one strange thing: everything works perfect with google chrome either from server or local. Why ie can not pull web site correctly from server, but chrome can? have you any idea?

Comment: Can you use the developer console to see if there are any error's in the console or 'network' tab?

Comment: One thing I've noticed with IE and CSS is that sometimes using relative addresses to resources (like fonts etc) causes issues. Is the site available to view?

Comment: Has IE cached any older content?  Are there any JavaScript errors?  Bad response codes for page resources?  Does the DOM validate?

Comment: what Ver of IE are you using? and are yo using the Respond.js and be sure to have this in your code <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: Site is not available because our network is not open so not connected to internet. IE 9.0.8 is installed to all computers. Javascript works well (textbox js validations are working). Opening developer console is restricted in internet explorer but I can open developer tools in chrome but as I said everything works well in chrome. I didn't use Respond.js but I will try it and write the result next morning.